# HTML Bootstrap grid columns not aligning

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to align filter boxes into a grid that spans 3 blocks per row...

I didn't want to lose the bootstrap look so I haven't tried to strip out some of these navbar/input group classes. Is there a clean way to fix this? What approach should I take to troubleshooting stuff like this in the future? jsFiddle below

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" ng-if="filterOn">
<form class="navbar-form"> <span class="input-group col-sm-4"> <span class="input-group-addon">Filter: </span>

    <input class="form-control" ng-model="filterOptions.filterText" />
    </span> <span class="input-group col-sm-4"> <span class="input-group-addon" style="width: 20%">Filter A: </span>

    <select class="form-control" name="mySelect1" ng-model="sel1">
        <option></option>
        <option>{{selections}}</option>
    </select>
    </span> <span class="input-group col-sm-4"> <span class="input-group-addon">Filter B: </span>

    <select class="form-control" name="mySelect2" ng-model="nameVarTo">
        <option></option>
        <option>selections2</option>
    </select>
    </span>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u1wffrd4/1/

Comment: Do you want 3 rows or 3 columns?

Comment: Do not use "input-group col-sm-4" classes in one tag, add another div as parent for it and then use "col-sm-4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.input-group {
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" ng-if="filterOn">
        <form class="navbar-form">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <span class="input-group"> 
                <span class="input-group-addon"  style="width: 20%">Filter: </span>
                <input class="form-control" ng-model="filterOptions.filterText" />
            </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <span class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon" style="width: 20%">Filter A: </span>
                <select class="form-control" name="mySelect1" ng-model="sel1">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>{{selections}}</option>
                </select>
            </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <span class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"  style="width: 20%">Filter B: </span>

                <select class="form-control" name="mySelect2" ng-model="nameVarTo">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>selections2</option>
                </select>
            </span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah great. So one more thing: Why won't the elements fill their full width at 1/3rd of the width of the row?

Comment: put .input-group { width:100%; } in your css. And you can specific the all label width for 20%. I updated above

Comment: That's perfect, thank you. Is it bad practice to edit the bootstrap.css directly? I should be extracting to a custom.css and using a class like `.input-group .fullwidth { width: 100%; }`, right?

Comment: Ok. One last thing I've noticed is that the labels will adjust width depending on the amount of text inside them. Do you know how to get them all to be the same width when the filter labels text length varies

Answer (score 0):

```
   

     .input-group.col-xs-4.col-md-4 {
        float: left;
        padding: 5px;
    }
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <nav ng-if="filterOn" class="navbar navbar-default">
        <form class="navbar-form">
 <div class="show-grid">
            <span class="input-group col-xs-4 col-md-4"> <span class="input-group-addon">Filter: </span>

                <input ng-model="filterOptions.filterText" class="form-control">
            </span>
            <span class="input-group col-xs-4 col-md-4"> <span class="input-group-addon" style="width: 20%">Filter A: </span>

                <select class="form-control" name="mySelect1" ng-model="sel1">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>{{selections}}</option>
                </select>
            </span>
            <span class="input-group col-xs-4 col-md-4"> <span class="input-group-addon">Filter B: </span>

                <select class="form-control" name="mySelect2" ng-model="nameVarTo">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>selections2</option>
                </select>
            </span>
  </div>
        </form>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your code with .container or .container-fluid and .row classes.
Check this http://jsfiddle.net/manishrane1/u1wffrd4/2/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" ng-if="filterOn">
        <form class="navbar-form">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><span class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">Filter: </span>

                <input class="form-control" ng-model="filterOptions.filterText" />
            </span></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4"><span class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon" style="width: 20%">Filter A: </span>

                <select class="form-control" name="mySelect1" ng-model="sel1">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>{{selections}}</option>
                </select>
            </span></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4"><span class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">Filter B: </span>

                <select class="form-control" name="mySelect2" ng-model="nameVarTo">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>selections2</option>
                </select>
            </span></div>
        </form>
    </nav>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```